# How to create Id based PUT/POST but details in the response in DRF?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a situation where a model has a foreign key with details. Ex. there are two models

```
class Person(models):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)

class Country(models):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Assume countries have been created beforehand. Now, I want the APIs for `Person` to take only `country Id` in `POST/PUT` requests but return the details of that country instead of only Id.

```
Request
{
   "id": 1,
   "country": 9
}
Response
{
   "id": 1,
   "country": {
       "id": 9,
       "name": "Some Country"
    }
}
```

I'm using Django Rest Framework. (I can write serializers which either take `id` in both read and write APIs or take the entire country object)

Comment: I actually implemented it in the same way after going through some github discussion. I created a country and country_detail field, the latter of which is read only and shows the detail.

Comment: you can use _HyperlinkedModelSerializer_ on Country Serializer and also make sure to add the _HyperlinkedRelated_ field in Country so that a Country have all the detail links to the person in current Country. Also go through the documentation on this [topic](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedrelatedfield). Hope it helps you !

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom field `CountryField` for this and user `to_representation` method to return object details:

```
class CountryDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class CountryField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        country = models.Barcode.objects.get(pk=value.pk)
        serializer = CountryDetailSerializer(country)
        return serializer.data

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Country.objects.all()
```

And use it in Person serializer:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country = CountryField()
```